# Inviting someone to co-author a paper

Tags: publications, authorship

I recently passed the M.Sc.

While I was reviewing a paper I found it interesting and potentially useful. I am planning to adopt the analyses that are utilized at that paper in my area of interest. The applications are quite different.

Is it feasible, usual and professional to propose that paper's first author (he is a post-doc student) to participate in my future work?

How about the contribution, to be more exact, the order of names?

How I can politely ask him for his contribution?

Comment: By the way I won't refer to a post-doc as a "student".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How I can politely ask him for his contribution?**

Just sent him/her an email with a brief summary of the ideas you are interested in and ask him/her if he/she is interested on the project, it has worked for me. Otherwise, try to attend one of his/her talks and approach him/her and the end of the talk, if possible.

**How about the contribution, to be more exact, the order of names?**

Perhaps it is too early to discuss about this ("Before one brings home the bacon one must kill the pig"). Who knows whether he/she is going to generalise or improve the ideas you propose or he/she would barely be involved in the project (you will come across all sorts of characters while doing research). A safe option is to use the alphabetical order. It helps to avoid many ego-fights. Start with a document without the name of the authors. If you end-up with something worthy of publication, put the cards on the table and ask directly "what order would you be more comfortable with?" or "would you be happy with the order '**ME** and *John Doe*'? ".

Comment: It is _never_ too early to discuss authorship and author-ordering expectations.  It may be too early to make a _decision_ about who will be first author, but the _standard_ for making that decision should be clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

**How I can politely ask him for his contribution?**
Say, "I read your paper... It gave me the following idea... Would you be interested in working on it with me?"

**How about the contribution, to be more exact, the order of names?**
Because you are initiating the research, chances are good that you will be the main contributor. If you are sure that you will or want to be first author/main contributor, write your name first in the list of authors in the drafts. If you are not sure, write the names in alphabetical order, and in parentheses "temporarily in alphabetical order". As soon as it becomes clear that one or two people are contributing more than you, suggest to them that their names should appear before yours (unless you know things will change later). Just keep the discussion open.